# Call to Object method, executing a closure Property - Error

Tags: php, oop

I have 2 classes, an event which holds the associated sessions the listener will check for and the method to execute and also a listener which monitors the sessions on page load and executes the corresponding event to that.

```
class Event
{
    private $Sesh;
    private $Method;

    public function set(
        $sesh = array(),
        $method
    ) {
        $this->Sesh = $sesh;
        $this->Method = $method;
    }

    public function get(
    ) {
        return [$this->Sesh,$this->Method];
    }
}

class Listener
{
    private $Sesh;
    public function setSesh(
        $foo
    ) {
        $this->Sesh = $foo;
    }

    private $Event;
    public function set(
        $foo,
        Event $event
    ) {
        $this->Event[$foo] = $event;
    }

    public function dispatch(
        $foo
    ) {
        $state = true;

        if(isset($this->Event[$foo]))
        {
            foreach($this->Event[$foo]->get()[0] as $sesh)
            {
                if(!isset($this->Sesh[$sesh]) || empty($this->Sesh[$sesh]))
                {
                    $state = false;
                }
            }
        }

        // this line seems to be the cause at the method closure execution - not sure why?
        return ($state) ? [true,$this->Event->get()[1]()] : [false,"Event was not triggered."];
    }
}
```

When I run something like this:

```
$e = new Event;
$e->set(['misc'], function() { return 'Event method called.'; });

$l = new Listener;
$l->setSesh(array('misc' => 'example'));
$l->set('example', $e);
$l->dispatch('example');
```

I am getting this error:

> FATAL ERROR Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on array in /home/phptester.net/public_html/code.php70(5) : eval()'d code:55 Stack trace: #0 /home/phptester.net/public_html/code.php70(5) : eval()'d code(65): Listener->dispatch('example') #1 /home/phptester.net/public_html/code.php70(5): eval() #2 {main} thrown on line number 55

Which seems to correspond to the method execution in the dispatch method of the Listener object, although I don't see why it is doing this? I am running PHP 7.0

My expected output in this case would be a returned array from the dispatch method containing: true and a string - 'Event method called.'

EDIT:

```
// returns array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "misc" }
var_dump($this->Event[$foo]->get()[0]);

// returns object(Closure)#2 (0) { }
var_dump($this->Event[$foo]->get()[1]);

// returns expected string output
var_dump($this->Event[$foo]->get()[1]());
```

Comment: gg @kyliethomas

Comment: rip more like, time loss x( xD @Jek

Comment: Ahahah pfft the feels, you should add me on Skype :) - `jackhalesyy`

Comment: Will do, I'll get round to doing that asap on my phone as it stands @Jek noted it though!

Comment: It's just that I need more coder friends

Comment: Your not coming up on the Skype directory, feel free to add mine - kaydotm8 @Jek